# What can the solution to Laplace's equation tell us?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, potential, voltage, gauss-law

If $V$ satisfies ${\nabla}^2V=0$ given the boundary conditions associated to the boundaries of some volume $\tau$ in space, then what can $V$ tell us?

Does it tell us the potential in all of space? Or just within $\tau$?

Does it tell us about the source of the potential? Whether it's a disc of charge, or sphere of charge, etc.?

Comment: You mean $\Delta V = 0$? Please make the problem formulation clearer, otherwise it's not that good to answer. $\mathbb{R}$ is typically reserved for the real numbers.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience, i have edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In electrostatics you obtain the Laplace equation from combining Gauß' law
$$
\nabla \cdot \vec{D} = \rho
$$
for the dielectric displacement $\vec{D}$ and the charge density $\rho$ with
a) a material law, often (and in vaccuum or air in particular)
$$
\vec{D} = \varepsilon_0 \vec{E}
$$
and b) the fact that because of Faraday's law the electric field can be obtained as the gradient of a potential,
$$
\vec{E} = - \nabla \phi\,.
$$
You obtain (the Poisson equation)
$$
\Delta \phi = - \frac{\rho}{\varepsilon_0}\,,
$$
which means that if the righthand-side is zero there are no sources that create the potential (at least in the region where $\Delta \phi = 0$, e.g. in you given volume).

As to the first part of your question: Yes, in a boundary value problem where you solve Laplace's equation in a given volume with given boundary conditions, the result will be the potential just in that volume.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking more, I would like to know more about the last part of your answer: the potential is solved for inside the volume. Why can't I just extend whatever the potential is inside the volume to all space? There is no restriction for what the potential must be outside the volume after all, as long as it continues smoothly to the other side.

Comment: You could, of course, yes. That would be solving Laplace's equation in the complement of the volume. As long as you add boundary conditions at infinity (vanishing potential, probably) that's absolutely fine.